# JSON response error when making an API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get capture the JSON response from an API and I am getting the below error. I want to understand why this error is showing up.

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

> Not Authorized
>   HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.

```js
{
  "membershipId": 190000,
  "organizationId": 0,
  "paymentFrequency": "Month",
  "effectiveDate": "2016-11 30T00:00:00",
  "promoPackageCode": "P56S",
  "rebatePercentage": 17.861,
  "rateDetails": [
    {
      "rateType": 0,
      "rateDescription": "CurrentRate",
      "rebate": "Y",
      "amount": 123.45
    },

    {
      "rateType": 1,
      "rateDescription": "PromoRate",
      "rebate": "Y",
      "amount": 155.75
    },

    {
      "rateType": 2,
      "rateDescription": "PromoRateDiff",
      "rebate": "Y",
      "amount": 32.30
    },
    {
      "rateType": 3,
      "rateDescription": "NonRebateCurrentRate",
      "rebate": "N",
      "amount": 150.3
    },
    {
      "rateType": 4,
      "rateDescription": "NonRebatePromoRate",
      "rebate": "N",
      "amount": 189.65
    },
    {
      "rateType": 5,
      "rateDescription": "NonRebatePromoRateDiff",
      "rebate": "N",
      "amount": 39.35
    }
  ]
};
```

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Comment: Given the response code, the issue is because you haven't passed valid credentials to the server in the request you make. We need to see the code to be able to help you. Please also take care to format your questions, as frankly, this is a barely readable mess. I edited the question to only show the error responses as the HTML formatting is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not passing authentication key in header. The message shows , you have not sufficient right to access the api.

Answer (score 0):

in the API ajax request you need to add a key (you request it from the API site) to the HTTP link.